# Reading data from the website

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy, indy10, idhttp

[image]

I am asking for help in accessing the website http://dctgdansk.pl/pl/strefa-klienta/sprawdz-kontener-online/ from the code level.

There is a "Container number" window in which the container number should be entered and after pressing the arrow data on a given container is made available.

Unfortunately, the source of the page does not have such information that can be loaded into my program via the function **IdHTTP1->Get (address)**.

I do not have experience in reading data from websites, but in one case, which I use in the address of the page, all data necessary to open another page appears, in this case, the website address is unchanged.

Comment: You need to use `POST` instead of `GET`. [POST request with IdHTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443511). Besides, it is not exactly clear what your actual problem is. Why do you tag your question with c++ if you use Delphi? SO is a place to help you with existing code, so you should show some code you have and describe exactly which part of the code does not work as expected, and what you expect that it should do.

Comment: I use C++ and Delphi sometimes. If I use IdHTTP1.Post('http://dctgdansk.pl/pl/strefa-klienta/sprawdz-kontener-online/', PostData); How can I be sure that the container number will go to the place marked "Container number" on the site?

Answer (score 0):

The Container Number is submitted using a standard HTML webform:

```
<form action="https://dctgdansk.pl/pl/strefa-klienta/sprawdz-kontener-online/" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="cntrnumber" name="cntrnumber" value="Container Number:" class="default"/>
  <input type="submit" value="szukaj"/>
</form>
```

To submit such a webform using Indy's `TIdHTTP` component, use the overloaded version of the `Post()` method that takes a `TStrings` as input, eg:

```pascal
var
  Params: TStringList;
  Response: string;
begin
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('cntrnumber=' + ContNum);
    Response := IdHTTP1.Post('https://dctgdansk.pl/pl/strefa-klienta/sprawdz-kontener-online/', Params);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
  // use Response as needed ...
end;
```