# RAD Studio : C++ : How do I add custom Headers to a TNETHTTPCient Post Action

Tags: c++, ajax, rest

I am very stuck and I hope someone can help.
I have to modify an existing C++ project to interact with an external system using a new API which is based on REST. I have very little web development experience, so forgive my ignorance.

It turns out this third party REST server doesn't like the REST components in RAD studio! While I can easily get sources on the internet to work, this system just throws authorisation errors. I have used other components with varying success. I have tried using TIdHTTP ***TNETHTTPClient*** & TNETHTTPRequest components. I have no idea which is best as part of my issue is unfamiliarity with the components...and the difficulty I have in finding examples covering what I believe I need to do. It really doesn't help that there have been Zero C++ Builder books since 2002?!

OK , so this is what I have to "replicate" , but within a C++ application

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:
"http://localhost/WebService/api/Actions/ExecuteAction?actionTypeFullName=SomeProduct.SecondGen.Common.Actions.DoSomething={GUID returned from login call},
headers: {
          'Expose-Headers': 'session-id',
          'session-id': sessionID // sessionID returned from login call
         },
data: {
   PropertyNames: [“TargetType”,”TargetID”]
   Propertyvalues: [“SecondGen.Common.Objects.Thing”,”5000”]
   SourceName: clientName
  },
dataType: JSON,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
success: function (msg) {
                     var result = msg;
                     displayResponse(result, responseType, "success");
                    },
error: function (errorMsg) {
                        displayResponse(errorMsg, responseType, "error");
                       }
});
```

This is as far as I have gotten (see code below). When run I get a 401 status...so access denied.
I think(?) the headers are not right but I can't be sure as I've struggled to find any examples of this being done...and I don't know how to check what I'm sending.

I have managed to complete the login function correctly using NETHTTPClient->Post(URL,TStringList) . It returned a GUID which I stored in this->Edit_Session_GUID->Text...so the session guid IS being supplied

Note :

- During login. I did not (could not) use variables passed with the URI
- During login. Passing the variables as a TStringList did work
- The Login Function **didn't** require any headers.

All calls following "Logging in" **do** require a GUID to be supplied in a header
(as shown in the following AJAX call).

Here's some of my code. I expect there's a lot wrong as I feel quite clueless

```
void __fastcall TForm2::RESTFunction ( void )
{
  UnicodeString REST_URL      = L"http://localhost/WebService/api/";
                REST_URL     += L"Actions/ExecuteAction?actionTypeFullName=";
                REST_URL     += L"SomeProduct.SecondGen.Common.Actions.DoSomething=";
                REST_URL     += L"={"+this->Edit_Session_GUID->Text+"}";

  this->EditURL->Text         = REST_URL;        //Display the URL, confirm it's OK
  // Set up HTTP Client Object
  this->HTTP_Client->Asynchronous                = false;
  this->HTTP_Client->HandleRedirects             = true;
  this->HTTP_Client->UserAgent                   = L"My Client/1.0";
  this->HTTP_Client->ContentType                 = L"application/json";
  this->HTTP_Client->AcceptEncoding              = L"UTF-8";
  // Set up Headers - this is what I think might be wrong ??
  this->HTTP_Client->CustHeaders->Clear();
  this->HTTP_Client->CustHeaders->Add(L"Expose-Headers","session-id");
  this->HTTP_Client->CustHeaders->Add(L"session-id",this->Edit_Session_GUID->Text);
  // Set up Function Variables/DATA and Run a Post Action
  // I've been trying different combinations of quotes { ' or \" or nothing }
  // as I don't know what's right
  UnicodeString PropertyNames = L"PropertyNames:['TargetTypez','TargetID']";
  UnicodeString Propertyvalues= L"Propertyvalues:['SomeProduct.SecondGen.Common.Objects.iThing', 5000]";
  UnicodeString sourceName    = L"SourceName:MyConnection";
  UnicodeString Tmp_params    = PropertyNames
                              + Propertyvalues
                              + sourceName;
  TStringStream *REST_parameters   = new TStringStream( Tmp_params );
  try
  {
     this->MemoWEBResponse->Lines->Text = this->HTTP_Client->Post(REST_URL, REST_parameters)->ContentAsString();
  }
  __finally
  {
     // can't deleted REST_parameters if web request is set to Asynchronous
     delete REST_parameters;
  }
}
```

Note : I switched from TStringList (in the login function) to TStringStream (in this function)  based on a post I saw by Remy Lebeau. I imagine they are roughly equivalent but he suggested this was better?

Things I would like to achieve

- fix this function call (confirm where I'm going wrong)
- find good instructions/examples on the use of NETHTTPClient over a wide range of scenarios (the youtube vids and "skill sprints" I've found seem quite basic, and the docwiki site seems almost devoid of C++ examples.
  (If there is an actual C++ Builder book released for "Seattle" or later please let me know!)
- I would like to be able to extract the details of what the NETHTTPClient is expecting to send so I can compare it to the AJAX sample I have. I haven't spotted anything I could use yet. This may help with debugging for other function calls.
- I would like to be able to see what the server is receiving from my calls. all I've found so far is C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 which seems to contain a basic history (history summarised in a way that hides a lot of detail). If you know how this can be done, I'd love to know!

Any insights you can offer would be gratefully received!
Thank you all. Stay safe.

Comment: RE : After a bit of googling I am likely to try to use WireShark to capture some of the traffic, not got as far as trying this yet as I've been playing with IdHTTP and linking this to an IdLogDebug component as this intercepts the send and receive for IdHTTP.

I couldn't find any specific examples of this in use but I pieced together a number of posts (again by Remy, Thank you!) that resulted in me adding the following to the following to 
IdLogDebug->OnShow(TIdConnectionIntercept *ASender, TIdBytes &ABuffer)
{ 
this->MemoWEBCall->Lines->Text = BytesToString(ABuffer); 
}

Comment: have had a crack at using wireshark today. If using an HTTPS web address you need to set chrome to save keys...watch this for info ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qecyZHL-GU ). I also found that when running wireshark on the server. http traffic from browsers (or C++apps) on the server don't show up. running http requests from a different machine do show up in wireshark

Comment: this will probably be my last update till I have a solution. I hope this will help anyone following in my footsteps (I've found entries on this site helpful). Wireshark has proved very helpful. I can see the calls being sent to the server and compare them with calls from the demo site.  
I switched to the TIdHTTP component and had problems...Wireshark helped me see the effect of variable types (TStringList,TStringStream,TMemoryStream,TIdMultiPartFormDataStream). Using TStringStream worked for the login...but not the function I posted here. So the search goes on....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can't say I completely understand the Whys and wherefores of it, but the observations of it I do follow.

**I could not have made these observations without wireshark. This seems to be a tool you need to learn to use!**

So the answer: the AJAX side of things seems to be doing translations and transformations *before* sending the data to the server. Here's the original "data block"

```
data: {
   PropertyNames: [“TargetType”,”TargetID”]
   Propertyvalues: [“SecondGen.Common.Objects.Thing”,”5000”]
   SourceName: clientName
  },
```

when the AJAX call is intercepted by Wireshark it looks like this

```
Form item: "PropertyNames[]" = "TargetType"
Form item: "PropertyNames[]" = "TargetID"
Form item: "Propertyvalues[]" = "SecondGen.Common.Objects.Thing"
Form item: "Propertyvalues[]" = "5000"
Form item: "SourceName" = "TestPage"
```

the same functionality is not present in Indy components, or the new built in Embarcdero TNETHTTP components. You have to send the data pre-translated to :

```
"PropertyNames[]= TargetType"
"& PropertyNames[]=TargetID"
"& Propertyvalues[]=SecondGen.Common.Objects.Thing"
"& Propertyvalues[]=5000"
"& SourceName=TestPage"
```

Note that without including the "&" character, wireshark does not show the "Form item :" text so the packet is effectively considered "malformed"

In the end I was using Devart Securebridge components (ScHttpWebRequest) as I will need a SignalR Hub component soon and this is part of their component library. In all likelihood it will be the same for both Indy TIdHTTP and Embarcadero TNETHTTP. I just need time to try modifying the data: payload for my amusement/education.

Aside : The data packet format (variable type) I used with the devart components was a TStringStream with ->WriteString & ->Poition=0 functions.

Comment: I removed the mention of Remmy, because I can't find what you're referring to (there's no comments or answers with that username on this post).

Comment: fair enough if you want to remove the reference to Remy. However Remy Lebeau has been answering questions for people since the dawn of time. I can't count the number of times I've seen helpful responses (on this site and others) when I've been googling to find solutions to my own problems. This user deserves to be recognised for all they have done for the community so I am happy to sing their praises. Resposnes they made (specifically regarding attaching data to TNetHTTP and TIdHTTP components) have been helpful in getting me to understand how to use these components

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable. It needs to be done in the appropriate context though, i.e. where you're thanking them for something specific, rather than just thanking them for help you've gotten before. By the way, I just noticed that you mention a post by Remy in the question. You should go ahead and add a link to that specific post, in order to give other readers useful context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443511/post-request-with-idhttp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365278/posting-form-data-with-idhttp-in-delphi

here's a couple of pages I noted down as comments in my code to refer back to for explanations on formatting data blocks. *both* include advice from Remy

there's a lot more I found, but I didn't save links to all of them